# What means this texture.zzzz, texture.xy, texture.xz etc

Tags: shader, cg

I stumbled upon on this coordinates

```js
texture.zzzz, texture.xy, texture.xz etc
```

What do this means or give reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s called [swizzling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swizzling_(computer_graphics)), and it’s a way of moving components of a vector around to make a new vector. Your first example, `.zzzz`, produces a 4-component vector where every component is the third component (`z`) of the original vector, so if `texture` contains the values (1,2,3,4) then the result is (3,3,3,3). Similarly, `.xz` produces a 2-component vector with the first (`x`) and third (`z`) components—using the same `texture` value, the result would be (1,3).